# Spatial Data Cluster in sql-server ? ( like ST_ClusterWithin in Postgis )

Tags: sql-server, clustering, spatial

Postgres 9.5 providing ST_ClusterWithin for Cluster the spatial data in DB level.

Is there any available solution for data clustering in MS SQL (NOT SERVER CLUSTER)

OR

Is there Any Function ( like ST_ClusterWithin ) in MS SQL Server

------------NO POSTGRES/ POSTGIS SOLUTION -------------

------------NO OL3 SOLUTION -------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked a the description of ST_ClusterWithin, I believe the geography::[Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx) and [STDistance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) methods are what you're looking for. (See Serge's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004474/merge-stored-procedure-and-ctefunction-together-to-get-results-from-reference for an example.)

Comment: Spatial Cluster gives a less amount of data and their count instead of million of data.  It will combine nearby data together, It is very helpfull for showing huge data.

Comment: You might have better luck posting at http://gis.stackexchange.com/